# quickSort for C strings

Tags: c, string, quicksort

I'm trying to make a quicksort that sorts c strings instead of ints. When I call quickSort all the strings in my array are emptied and unsorted and I cant figure out why

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
    void swap(char** A, int i, int j){
       //printf("swap\n");
       char* temp=malloc(strlen(A[i])*sizeof(char));
       temp = A[i];
       free(A[i]);
       A[i]=malloc((1+strlen(A[j])) * sizeof(char));
       A[i] = A[j];
       free(A[j]);
       A[j] = malloc((1+strlen(temp)) * sizeof(char));
       A[j]=temp;
    }

    int Partition(char** A, int p, int r){
        //printf("partion\n");
       int i, j;
       char* x;
       //printf("x\n");
       x = A[r];
       i = p-1;

       for(j=p; j<r; j++){
          if( strcmp(A[j], x) < 0){
             i++;
             swap(A, i, j);
          }
       }
       swap(A, i+1, r);
       return(i+1);
    }

    void QuickSort(char** A, int p, int r){
       int q;
       if( p<r ){
          q = Partition(A, p, r);
          QuickSort(A, p, q-1);
          QuickSort(A, q+1, r);
       }
    }
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Comment: Is this for an assignment or something? Otherwise use `qsort()`.

Comment: That `swap()` function is all sorts of wrong. Why in the world are you using `malloc()` in it?  And then promptly assigning new values to the variables holding the pointer to the allocated memory, causing memory leaks galore, and use after free bugs later...

Comment: thanks, twas the swap function causing the porblems